# Error ArrayList cannot find symbol symbol: variable myAl location: class JavaApplication into main

Tags: java

Why does this error happen?

[image]

I create an array inside the main:

```
List<Integer> myAL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Add items to that array, then call the findNumber method:

```
findNumber(myAl, 2);
```

But an error appears:
Error ArrayList cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable myAl   location: class JavaApplication

Comment: `myAL` vs `myAl` (Notice the capital L)

Comment: and also you are trying to access non static method in static area directly

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems.
Your immediat problem as GBlodgett already pointed out us that you did not pay attention to your names one is "myAl" the other is "myAL".

The second which will occur directly after is that you can't call a non static method like findNumber out of a static code block.

The third is that your return value, the String findNumber returns will get lost. You can either assign it to a variable String newString = findNumber... ;
Or what you probably want here is to print it with System.out.println(findN...);

For the future, it is nice if you can include the code directly instead of a picture, as it is easier to copy code instead of recreate it from a picture.

Happy Coding

As a personal tip, stay away from the main if you just want to write some silly code and run JUnit tests instead.

```
@Test
void test()
{
    myAl.add(0);
    ....
    findNumber(..);
}
```

extra points if you use assertions and good test, but that can wait until you get your feet under you. Tough it can help tremendiously to write tests instead of relying on print debugging